# pollution degree and creepage distance

Tags: pcb, clearance, creepage

I read in some books that pollution degree can influence the creepage distance in electronic  circuits, is there any relation (mathematical) between the pollution degree and the creepage distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pollution degree is an empirical characteristic and not a real physical quantity, so no, there will be no strict analytical formula. The next best thing is to take a table with creepage distance values for different pollution degrees and approximate these values with some kind of function (usually a polynom).

Comment: If your designing for a standard it will usually have a requirement based on expected transients (Rated impulse withstand voltage) the device is to be able to withstand. Industrial IEC 60947 uses 5.5mm as a default but it can be reduced to 0.1mm based on very good transient control.